# Maven: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException involving org.codehaus.plexus types: how do I fix this?

Tags: java, maven, illegalargumentexception

While running `mvn test -P myproj -e --projects uaa -X` over the
     CloudFoundry uaa code I hit this error message:

```
 [WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo
 com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:


 1) Error injecting: 
        private org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.manager.CompilerManager 
        org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.compilerManager
   while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo
   at ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2, 
        parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@3a2c4ede]
   while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo annotated with 
        @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=
               org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile)
 1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1006)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:260)
    ... 23 more
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
      Can not set org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.manager.CompilerManager field
          org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.compilerManager to
          org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.manager.DefaultCompilerManager
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(
            UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
 [...59 lines omitted...]
```

Plugins loaded from 7 different pom.xml files in the structure:

```
groupId:artifactId:version
======= ========== =======
foundrylogic.vpp:vpp:2.2.1
:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.9
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.6
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:1.5
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.1
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:2.1.2
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.11
org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.0-beta-1
org.codehaus.mojo:maven-emma-plugin:1.0-alpha-3
org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:2.2
```

Anyone know how to fix the IllegalArgumentException?

Comment: Could you show us your pom file please?

Comment: http://kopy.io/UkA9f

Answer (score 0):

Problem "solved" by downgrading Maven from 3.2.3 to 3.0.5